# Google Maps of my country only?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

How can I use Google maps in Android app so that it only shows my country?

I mean so that the rest of the world is not featured in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out one of [Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm)' great GMaps tutorials - he shows you how to limit zoom and pan in your map.

If you want some areas to be non-visible, [you can try this one:](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/einsertg.htm) I think that's closest to what you want (the [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_egroundoverlay.htm) actually does a similar thing to what you want, using USA as the example).