# How to block the view of Google Maps on one country?

Tags: android, google-maps, screen, padding, country

My app shows only markers in my country, so i don't need the rest of the world showing on screen. Is it possible to fix the padding on map within a rectangle around my country?

Comment: See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639341/3168859)

Comment: I read this http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm but i need to see code to figure out how to apply it. Can you help me?

Comment: Well..I dont know how to do that...But see this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/77TzreuY37c)..I feel like you'll get some ideas from there...

Comment: I think both links you have posted are related to Javascript API. setCenter() and setZoom() method don't exist...

Comment: Do you need the map to start with a current position and zoom, or to block the user from moving it somewhere else? Or both?

Comment: I need both. The app starts on a position and on a zoom and the user can't move outside the part of the map that appears at the startup. He can make moves on map only if he makes zoom-in...